# jQuery Mobile listview detail page after deleting item clicking the browser back button goes back to the deleted item detail view

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile listview detail page after deleting item clicking the browser back button goes back to the deleted item detail view.

I am writing an application using jQuery Mobile framework, in a page, a listview is dynamically created for the user to add product name. When user clicks on a listview item link will once again dynamically generate a details view page to show the details of the product.

In the details view, there is a delete button for the user to click to remove this item from the list and go back to the listview page.

The problem is happening when the user clicks the browser back button, the previously deleted list item detail view page shows up again. This is not correct, firstly the deleted item is not in the list any more it confuses the user. Secondly, if i remove the hidden details view page, this will mess up with the history object, what can i do in this situation, how can i fix this? I will created a jsfiddle link for this.
Thank you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BeiHua_Xie1/h0bweavo/

Comment: I loaded your jsFiddle but didn't understand what to enter in order to see an illustration of the problem.  Can you describe how to use your jsFiddle to see the nature of the problem?

Comment: In the jsFiddle link page, please type prod1 in the Product name input box,

Comment: and then type 1 in the Display order for product input box, after clicking the Add button. Clicking the prod1 listview link item, in the Product detail view page, please click the Delete button. It will jump back to the listview page, at this time please click your web browser back button at the top left corner. See the Product details view page shows up again. This is not corrrect because it was just been deleted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want jQuery Mobile to update browser's navigation history, you should disable `changeHash` upon navigating. Therefore, upon hitting back button, you'll be redirected to previous page in history to current page.

Also note that `$.mobile.changePage()` is deprecated and replaced with the below function.

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", newPage, {
    changeHash: false /* this won't update navigation history */
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/r7eozme5/)**

Comment: @BeiHuaXie you're welcome :) don't forget to tag your question with jquery-mobile if they're related to it.